# HTML, CSS, JAVASCRIPT, PHP - putting it all together

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I'm new to web development, I know some javascript, `html`, `css` and I'm learning `php`. The problem is that I don't find good resource on how to put it all together.

Any recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Well. The problem is (was for me) the learning curve. Having read books that `tries to put js html php sql` together (even books `html-css together`). Has for me been. A total waste of time. Focus on sources (books, web) `that does one thing only` and does it well and throughout `is more time efficient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look in this [list-of-freely-available-programming-books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) here on SO for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "putting it all together" means in single page

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
//css here
</style>
<script language="javascript">
//js here
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>first page</h1>
   <?php
     //php code here
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good sense of humor, I'll give you that.

Answer (score 0):

Besides looking around Google (or similar) for tutorials, you can pick up a beginners book. We used [Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596157134) in a class I was a TA in, it's pretty good for learning the basics of web dev.